# Why isn't word-spacing working when specified?

Tags: html, css

I have my list now reading from left to right instead of reading row by row but now how do I space the words out as they are too close together? I'm trying to have space in between texts and tried doing word-spacing but it wouldn't change anything. I tried doing word-spacing in both #menu id and inside li{} but it still didn't work.

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="nav"></div>
        <img src="...">
        <h1>IndieForwardMusic</h1>

        <ul id="menu">
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li><a href="..."</a></li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</body>



#menu {
  position: absolute;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 38px;
  top: 10px;
}

li{
  float: left;
  word-spacing: 30px;
}
```

Comment: There is only one word in those `li` properties. Perhaps you are thinking of `letter-spacing`?

Comment: I have 4 words that are clumped up and too close together, I want there to be space in between each word so it would look nicer.

Comment: If you want to space the `li`s try `li  {margin-left: 30px; margin-right: 30px; }`. `word-spacing` cannot work here due to the reason @Jack mentioned.

Comment: Then you should use `li { margin: 0 30px; }`. `word-spacing` increases the spacing between words in a tag, so `<p>hello there</p>` becomes `hello____there` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `word-spacing` as in each `li` there is only one word. If you want to space the `li`s then use the following CSS

```
li {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just set some margin.

```
#menu li {
margin:0 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for stealing my idea I posted in the comment

Comment: Im sorry. I didn't see that you posted it before me.